# NTFS USB device seen, but not the partitions

Tags: usb, hard-drive, mount, partition, ntfs

I have a Toshiba 1TB USB external drive attached to a Raspberry Pi running:

```
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
```

The USB device is seen. It is creating a `/dev/sda`.

However, I can't mount the partition as the partitions don't appear to be seen?

The drive works fine attached to my OSX laptop. It has only one partition. This is the first time I've tried to mount any NTFS USB device on wheezy, so I apologize for any basic mistakes.

ntfs-3g is installed:

```
# apt-get install ntfs-3g
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ntfs-3g is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.


# parted /dev/sda
root@raspberrypi:/dev/disk/by-id# (no response)

# blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="583A-FB50" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/mmcblk0p3: LABEL="SETTINGS" UUID="2dd31240-fbd0-46d7-966d-5e2231c4350a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mmcblk0p5: LABEL="boot" UUID="042B-BC7E" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/mmcblk0p6: LABEL="root" UUID="45137191-b3b5-48e3-a48e-e47eac3d08e0" TYPE="ext4" 

# fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 8068 MB, 8068792320 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 246240 cylinders, total 15759360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d1f02

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            8192     1679687      835748    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2         1687552    15286271     6799360   85  Linux extended
/dev/mmcblk0p3        15286272    15351807       32768   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p5         1695744     1818623       61440    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p6         1826816    15286271     6729728   83  Linux

root@raspberrypi:/dev/disk/by-id# ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 180 May 15 09:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 Jan  1  1970 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Jan  1  1970 memstick-USD_0x56a51ada -> ../../mmcblk0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jan  1  1970 memstick-USD_0x56a51ada-part1 -> ../../mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jan  1  1970 memstick-USD_0x56a51ada-part2 -> ../../mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jan  1  1970 memstick-USD_0x56a51ada-part3 -> ../../mmcblk0p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 May 15 08:59 memstick-USD_0x56a51ada-part5 -> ../../mmcblk0p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 May 15 08:59 memstick-USD_0x56a51ada-part6 -> ../../mmcblk0p6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 15 09:26 usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20150813019068F-0:0 -> ../../sda

# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0480:a200 Toshiba America Info. Systems, Inc. 

# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda /media/usb/
Failed to read bootsector (size=0)
Failed to mount '/dev/sda': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/usb/
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sda1': No such file or directory

ntfs-3g 2012.1.15AR.5 external FUSE 29 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
        Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2011 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), remove_hiberfile, uid=, gid=,
          umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
          Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device is not detected in Raspberry. Probably there isn't enough power.
Do you have powered HUB? If you have Raspberry Pi 2 you can try to add `max_usb_current=1` to **config.txt** in boot partition, but each USB port is still limited to 500mA.

Comment: The Pi has NO control of current to individual ports. It is all or nothing.

Comment: It looks like it's detected (see lsusb and /dev/drive/by-id above). From the posted outputs...do you think it's not being seen properly?

Comment: It was the power. I used a y-split cable since the drive didnt have a separate power plug. Its seen fine now. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted to have a look at the partitions. Install it using `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Also, could you post a screenshot of your partitions in gparted.